# What is the difference between $dH$ and $\Delta H$, and why does integrating $dH$ give $\Delta H$?

Tags: thermodynamics

For example, the equation (under constant pressure) $$dH=C_p\, dT$$
is integrated to $$\Delta H = \int^{T_f}_{T_i} C_p \, dT $$.
What is the difference between the $dH$ and $\Delta H$?

Comment: You answered your own question: $\Delta H$ is the definite integral of $dH$. I presume you are familial with calculus.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about calculus. It is not specific to enthalpy.

Comment: @Themis understanding the mathematics is pertinent to a thorough understanding of thermodynamics

Comment: This has just become a weird question. The latest edit was weird, closure based on homework policy was weird, everything is weird.

Comment: We should revert the last change because it makes the reason for the closure AND the answers impossible to understand (it becomes a different question). Closure for Homework policy makes no sense. Closure for "it's calculus" makes sense for the original question. @ananta, if you want an answer to your edited version, it's better that you write your own question. Even if you partly already know the answer.

Comment: Agree with @Benoit. The question now appears to be "why do we write $\Delta H$ or $\Delta S$ but not $\Delta W$?", while the original question seemed to be about how integration works.

Comment: @Benoit I have not only included the original question on how integration works and what the difference between $dH$ and $\Delta H$ is but also made it more relevant to thermodynamics by adding a statement concerning exact and inexact differentials and how these relate to thermodynamic quantities.

All the answers are still relevant, albeit, some language issues. I will modify the question and the answers to correspond with each other, if the community supports this course of action. Your comments on how to improve the question further will be appreciated.

Comment: @anata. My comment essentially means that your question is good. But it is not the OP's question.  It is connected but too different to be in the same thread. Putting the two questions together creates a confusion because answers have already been posted. While apparently "simple", your question requires an answer by someone with solid notions in maths (and a bit physics). For example, $\delta W$ is not an inexact differential and few people know it. (while $\delta W_{rev}$ is). Your question is already good and worth asking as is imo.

Comment: Edit has been reverted.

Comment: @Benoit I am intrigued by your comment: why is $\delta W$ not an inexact differential while $\delta W_{rev}$ is? Could you point me to the right resources for this, or should I ask this as a separate question?

Answer (score 1):

The former is “the tiniest change in” while the latter is “a change in.” when you sum a lot of the tiniest changes, they build up into a larger change.

Answer (score 1):

Integration means summing infinite infinitesimal terms, which are $(dH)_P$'s in this case, to obtain an *area* of sorts.

Consider the following $C_p$–$T$ curve which is divided into (finite for illustration) divisions and summed over to obtain an (approximate) area *under the curve*, vis $\Delta H$. The inaccuracies are sown in red.

[image: obtaining approximate enthalpy change using Riemannian sum]

Now, if you keep increasing the number of (grey) boundaries, shown as fine spacing (if you can zoom in) below, you will notice that the approximation becomes more and more accurate (refer any university level calculus textbook).

[image: obtaining exact enthalpy change using Riemannian sum]

To answer your question, as to why does integrating $dH$ yeild $\Delta H$, the reason is that $H$ is a *state function*, and all "integrals of differentials" of state functions are *bistate functions*, which only depend on the initial and final states, for which we use the $\Delta$ notation. For a $path function$, such as $W$, $\int_1^2 dW = W$ does not make sense; even $\int_1^2 dW$ is not very accurate, since $\delta W$ (notice the change $d\rightarrow \delta$, as used by some authors), indicating that $W$ is a *path function*, is more accurate. Thus,  $\int_1^2 \delta W = W$ and *not* $\Delta W$.

Answer (score 0):

The former is called an (exakt) differential, it is so to say, Infinitely small while the second expression means a finite difference.